# Grouping days in order to see the number of items sold using DAX in power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

My data looks like this :

```
Item | Packaged Date | Delivery Date | Days took 
1    |   17-05-2019   | 19-05-2019   | 2
2    |   23-05-2019   | 24-05-2019    | 1 
3    |   22-05-2019   | 30-05-2019   | 8
```

I want to make a table using DAX where i have two columns

```
Number of Days | Items 
0-5             | 2 
5-10            | 1
```

This basically means within 5 days, 2 items in total were sold 
and within 5 or 5-10 days , 1 item was sold

Answer (score 0):

I found a way using DAX expression to solve the my own Question. 
I created a DAX Query :

```
AggregatedDays = IF(Dates[Days]<=5 && Dates[Days]>=0 , "0-5 Days","5-10 Days")
```

A new table is created using Aggregated Days column and Items with items being "sum" from the "VALUES" table.